# How to change connection for Logic App, when you are trying to trigger Logic app thorugh Email

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0K5r.png)[My logic app should trigger when a mail is received in the outlook inbox folder. But I am able to connect to only 1 outlook account. How can I add multiple Outlook accounts? I have a table created in my Azure Table, in that table there is a column 'From_EMAIL_ID', I need to configure this 'From_EMAIL_ID' parameter to my Connection. So in the future whenever new records for my 'From_EMAIL_ID' get inserted in this table, still I should be able to trigger the logic app. In Short, I want to bind the connection in the logic app to the field name 'FROM_EMAIL_ID' in the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxASU.png)azure table.][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPyKy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Currently a logic app cannot connect to multiple Outlook APIs, so that might be your issue if I'm understanding correctly. There is an open feedback item for this here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/40009840-logic-app-should-be-able-to-connect-multiple-outlo

You can send multiple emails by adding multiple emails to the "To" field, though. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-send-email?tabs=dotnet